# Split a string in ksh

Tags: text-editing, ksh

I am looking for a quick/easy way to split a string in ksh.

It has varied number delimiters (spaces) between each item.

Example:

```
value1 value2                  value3
```

Any suggestions/advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a for loop with the input string will split on whitespace.

```
LIST="value1  value2 value3"
for x in $LIST ; do
    echo $x
done
```

Yields

```
value1
value2
value3
```

or

```
LIST="value1  value2 value3"
set -A STRING "$LIST"
for x in $STRING ; do
    echo $x
done
```

Yields

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: Quick, easy, painless.  Thanks for the cogent answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array.

```
LIST="value1  value2 value3"
set -A values $LIST
echo ${values[0]}

value1
```

Answer (score 0):

Piping through sed and optionally grep works too

```
LIST="value1  value2 value3" ;
echo "$LIST" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' | grep .
```

You can drop the grep if you also drop the quotes which removes multiple spaces though other formatting may be effected.

```
LIST="value1  value2 value3" ;
echo $LIST | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g'
```